# How to scale down/up all deployments in a namespace except for one with an specific name on azure pipelines

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to know a way to scale down all the deployments on a kubernetes namespace except for one with a specific string inside the name since it has dependencies. This on an AzureCLI task inside of an azure pipeline. Any ideas?

Something like:
If name contains "randomname" then do not scale up/down the service.

I did try some exceptions but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a *label* on the one you want to exclude, and then use queries using [labels and selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#api) to apply operations on the selected set of resources.